# Can I use the model from an MVC partial view in my Knockout viewmodel in the main view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am currently working on a view that has several partial views within in, which might also have partial views in them.

I have set up a Knockout viewmodel for the entire view, which also covers the partial views. This is in a separate js file. I have set it up as one viewmodel as I will want to save it all as a whole. Maybe this is the wrong way to go about it and I should have different viewmodels for the different views.

The partial views have their own view models, which I want to use to populate the knockout viewmodel.

I have only been using Knockout for a few months, so I am not sure if this is possible or sensible. I would greatly appreciate any opinions or examples of how to do this, or any alternatives, e.g. should I used a separate knockout viewmodel for each partial and then post all back to the server as separate ajax?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhT9Id8Jfb8, do what you want and if something not working, then put the cod here and the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use knockout [component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) to get your particular html and js file. Using knockout components you will be able to separate your concerns entirely with the help of knockoutjs.
Lastly if you want to have more manageable Web Application you can use [durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) that work great using knockoutJs, jQuery and bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into your suggestions.